# why my map function is not working to display API data on browser?

Tags: reactjs, function, next.js, fetch-api, react-query

I am getting the data in console but, unable to find the correct path to map over data in nested map functions. I want an Image component for every product in array.
[image: API data in console]

```
I am trying this path to map over object given below in picture.
This is the query having async function that fetched the data.

   const res = useCategoriesQuery({
     type: query.type,
     text: query?.text,
     category: query?.category,
      });
     console.log(res);
```

[image: Map function]

The Error I am getting is -
[image: Error]

Comment: [why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: `category: query?.category` - the nullsafe operator here is probably a good indication that `category` may not always be an array. If that's the case, you need to account for that and check for its value before trying to use array methods on it. There's hundreds of questions on SO about this error, I'm sure you can make one of their answers work for your case.

Answer (score 3):

You have to map over the `data`:

```
res.data?.categories.data.map()
```

Comment: The null safe operator on `data` is pretty useless since if it is null it will break before it gets to the `map`.